# Can't make a connection with my SQL-Server with C++

Tags: c++, sql-server

I am running Visual Studio 2021 on a PC with OS Windows 10.

I want to make a connection to the MSSQL-server with a c++ application.
I did try many different connection strings, but I can not figure out why I can't connect to the server. I am still getting the following output : Could not connect to SQL Server.

Code below:

```
void configDatabase() {

    #define SQL_RESULT_LEN 240
    #define SQL_RETURN_CODE_LEN 3000

    //define handles and variables
    SQLHANDLE sqlConnHandle;
    SQLHANDLE sqlStmtHandle;
    SQLHANDLE sqlEnvHandle;
    SQLWCHAR retconstring[SQL_RETURN_CODE_LEN];

    //initializations
    sqlConnHandle = NULL;
    sqlStmtHandle = NULL;

    //allocations
    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &sqlEnvHandle)) {
        goto COMPLETED;
    }
        
    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLSetEnvAttr(sqlEnvHandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0)) {
        goto COMPLETED;
    }
        
    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlEnvHandle, &sqlConnHandle)) {
        goto COMPLETED;
    }
        
    //output
    cout << "Attempting connection to SQL Server...";
    cout << "\n";

    //connect to SQL Server  
    switch (SQLDriverConnect(sqlConnHandle, NULL,
        (SQLWCHAR*)TEXT("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=LAPTOP-KD0SFV4F\\MSSQLSERVER1,1433;DATABASE=dbFotfChallenge;UID=Tom;PWD=Tom;Trusted_Connection=no;"),
            SQL_NTS, retconstring, 1024, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT)) {
    case SQL_SUCCESS:
        cout << "Successfully connected to SQL Server";
        cout << "\n";
        break;
    case SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO:
        cout << "Successfully connected to SQL Server";
        cout << "\n";
        break;
    case SQL_INVALID_HANDLE:
        cout << "Could not connect to SQL Server";
        cout << "\n";
        goto COMPLETED;
    case SQL_ERROR:
        cout << "Could not connect to SQL Server";
        cout << "\n";
        goto COMPLETED;
    default:
        break;
    }

    //if there is a problem connecting then exit application
    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlConnHandle, &sqlStmtHandle))
        goto COMPLETED;

    //output
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Executing T-SQL query...";
    cout << "\n";

    //if there is a problem executing the query then exit application
    //else display query result
    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(sqlStmtHandle, (SQLWCHAR*)L"SELECT @@VERSION", SQL_NTS)) {
        cout << "Error querying SQL Server";
        cout << "\n";
        goto COMPLETED;
    }
    else {
        //declare output variable and pointer
        SQLCHAR sqlVersion[SQL_RESULT_LEN];
        SQLINTEGER ptrSqlVersion;
        while (SQLFetch(sqlStmtHandle) == SQL_SUCCESS) {
            SQLGetData(sqlStmtHandle, 1, SQL_CHAR, sqlVersion, SQL_RESULT_LEN, &ptrSqlVersion);
            //display query result
            cout << "\nQuery Result:\n\n";
            cout << sqlVersion << endl;
        }
    }
    //close connection and free resources
    COMPLETED:
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlStmtHandle);
    SQLDisconnect(sqlConnHandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlConnHandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, sqlEnvHandle);

    //pause the console window - exit when key is pressed
    cout << "\nPress any key to exit...";
    getchar();
```

Comment: Have you compared your `SQLDriverConnect` call against the one in the [Connection Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqldriverconnect-function#connection-attributes) example yet?

Comment: Restarted my pc... And it worked.... lol

Answer (score 0):

You have set `Trusted_Connection` to `no` instead of `false`.

`no` is not a valid value.